# Is there any better way to solve this geometric area problem?

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

Problem: [image]

I took quite a long time to solve (8 mins?). My work is in the photo. [image]

Short explanation: basically I set point C as (0,0) in a Cartesian plane, and progressively calculated the slopes of line $\overline{BP}$(denoted as $\alpha$ in my diagram), $\overline{QA}$($b$), $\overline{RD}$($c$), $\overline{CS}$($d$), and then the coordinate points of Q, R, S, T, which are denoted as φ, $\pi$, $\sigma$, $\phi$ respectively. Afterwards I use the shoelace formula and calculated the area of the central quadrilateral.

Anyone have a faster way?

Comment: Describing the lines with analytic geometry, like you've done, should be fairly fast. If you want to do it even quicker, I'd say just practice so you can intuit the equations of the lines faster and simplify the units, e.g., by assuming that the area is $1$ and then scaling it at the end.

Comment: "Afterwards I use daily the shoelace formula and calculated"  belongs with https://tricycle.org/trikedaily/green-koans/

Comment: do we have reason to think it's supposed to be faster ? Also you could type out images.

Comment: One tactic you could use to find the midpoints of lines faster is that the midpoint of $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2$ is $\left(\frac{x_{1}+x_{2}}{2},\frac{y_{1}+y_{2}}{2}\right)$, which is simple coordinate manipulation and doesn't involve the lines.

Comment: If you can write a page-full of equations and solve this problem in 8 minutes, you have nothing to complain about.  I suspect with several hours of work a good mathematician will find there are some shortcuts that could reduce it to 7.5 minutes...  At the very least use a calculator instead of writing out a long list of terms...

Comment: @WillJagy it was an autocorrect typo and I didn’t check back on this question afterwards for a few days. It should be fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Although using coordinates is a sure (yet brute-force) way to get the result, it may be more natural, or quicker, to solve it geometrically. First, conclude QP || RD and T is the midpoint of CS as well, from the trapezoid AQPX and the midpoints R, D and P.

Denote areas as [.] and I = [ABCD]. Then, the midpoint P implies [BCP] = $\frac14$I and the midpoint Q implies [ABQ] = $\frac14$I. Moreover, the distance ratio of Q to BC and AD is 1:3, implying [AQD] = $\frac38$I; and the distance ratio of R to BA and CD is 1:3, implying [RCD] = $\frac38$I. To summarize,

$$[BCP] =[ABQ]= \frac14I,\>\>\>\>\>\>\>[AQD] =[RCD] =\frac38I\tag 1$$

Then, the midpoints R, S and T lead to, respectively,

$$[ARD] =\frac12[AQD] =\frac3{16}I,\>\>\>\>\>
[CSD] =\frac12[RCD] =\frac3{16}I,\>\>\>\>\>
[TCP] =\frac14[CSD] =\frac3{64}I\tag 2$$

Recognize that the shaded area can be constructed with

$$[RQTS] = I - [BCP] - [ABQ] - [ARD] - [CSD] + [TCP]$$

Plug in the results (1) and (2), as well as the given I=1024, to arrive at,

$$[RQTS] = \left(1- \frac14-\frac14 -\frac3{16}-\frac3{16} + \frac3{64}\right)I=\frac{11}{64}\cdot 1024 = 176$$

Comment: Out of everything I think your way is very elegant, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Note that $\text{slope} \ \overleftrightarrow{QT} 
          =\text{slope} \ \overleftrightarrow{RS} = -2$

Hence $\square RSTQ$ is a trapezoid.

$\left(\text{Note: The slope of the line $Ax + By = C$ is $-\dfrac AB$} \right)$.

Since the line $\overleftrightarrow{RS}$ passes through the point $R=(20,24)$ its equation is

$$2x+y = 64 \quad (= 2(20) + 1(24))$$

The altitude of the trapezoid $\square RSTQ$ is the distance from the line $\overleftrightarrow{RS}$ to the point $T=(13,6)$ is

$$h = \dfrac{|2(13)+1(6)-64|}{\sqrt{2^2+1^2}} = \dfrac{32}{\sqrt 5}$$

Since $QT = 5\sqrt 5$ and $RS = 6\sqrt 5$ Then

$$\text{area} \square QRST = h \cdot \dfrac{QT + RS}{2} = 176$$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let $[\cdot]$ denote the area. 
Starting from the square $[ABCD]=a^2$,
we can cut $[QTSR]$ from it
by removing triangular pieces.

\begin{align}
[BCP]&=\tfrac14\,[ABCD]=\tfrac14\,a^2
,\\
[ABQ]&=\tfrac12\,[ABP]=\tfrac14\,a^2
,\\
[AQD]&=[ABCD]-2\,[ABQ]-\tfrac12\,[BCP]
=a^2-\tfrac12\,a^2-\tfrac18\,a^2
=\tfrac38\,a^2
,\\
[ARD]&=\tfrac12\,[AQD]
=\tfrac 3{16}\,a^2
,\\
[DRC]&=
\tfrac 34\cdot \tfrac12\,a^2=\tfrac 38\,a^2
,\\
[DSC]&=\tfrac12\,[DRC]=\tfrac 3{16}\,a^2
,\\
[DSP]&=\tfrac12\,[DSC]=\tfrac 3{32}\,a^2
,\\
[PST]&=\tfrac12\,[DSP]=tfrac 3{64}\,a^2
,\\
[QTSR]&=
[ABCD]-[BCP]-[ABQ]-[ARD]-[DSP]-[PST]
\\
&=a^2\cdot(1-\tfrac14-\tfrac14-\tfrac 3{16}
-\tfrac 3{32}-\tfrac 3{64})
\\
&=\tfrac{11}{64}\,a^2=176
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Let $RD$ intersect $AB$ at $U$. Since $PT\parallel DS$, $BPDU$ is a parallelogram that has the same area as the rectangle $BCPU$. It's now easy to figure out $\frac{QT}{BP}$ and $\frac{RS}{UD}$ and finish up.